# How to dynamically change Form Tab Titles in October CMS

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

Is there an efficient method or plugin to dynamically change a Form Tab's title in the October CMS backend?

Similar to how it's done from the Builder plugin, but a bit more user-friendly:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzHWQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for `backend.form.extendFieldsBefore` event. You can combine it with DB fetch data from DB and use here (which may be entered by the some user ..)

> Write down this in your plugin's boot method.

```php
<?php

class Plugin extends PluginBase
{
    public function boot() {

      \Event::listen('backend.form.extendFieldsBefore', function($widget) {

          if (!$widget->model instanceof \RainLab\User\Models\User) {
              // --------------------------------- ^ Check if its your modal 
              return; // other wise do nothing return
          }

          // rainlab.user::lang.user.account => 
          // translated to Account by Lang Manager

          // need to change  
          // "rainlab.user::lang.user.account" => 'My Account - OK'
          // if you need to change tab's title
          // you need to change it for all fields
          // which uses that same tab title

          foreach ($widget->tabs['fields'] as $key => $val) {
            if($val['tab'] === 'rainlab.user::lang.user.account') {
              $widget->tabs['fields'][$key]['tab'] = 'My Account - OK';
            }
          }

      });

    ...
}
```

> before result

[image]

> after result

[image]
if any doubt please comment

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you